# Jquery function to split option list into hierarchical select

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have  list that looks like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="All" selected="selected">- Any -</option>
    <option value="16">Africa</option>
    <option value="17">Asia</option>
    <option value="56">-China</option>
    <option value="57">-Japan</option>
    <option value="19">Canada</option>
    <option value="20">-Alberta</option>
    <option value="21">-British Columbia</option>
    <option value="22">-Manitoba</option>
    <option value="23">-New Brunswick</option>
    <option value="24">-Newfoundland &amp; Labrador</option>
    <option value="25">-Northwest Territories</option>
    <option value="26">-Nova Scotia</option>
    <option value="27">-Nunavut</option>
    <option value="28">-Ontario</option>
    <option value="29">-Prince Edward Island</option>
    <option value="30">-Quebec</option>
    <option value="31">-Saskatchewan</option>
    <option value="32">-Yukon</option>
    <option value="33">Central &amp; South America</option>
    <option value="34">Europe</option>
    <option value="35">Republic of Ireland</option>
    <option value="36">United Arab Emirates</option>
    <option value="37">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="38">-England</option>
    <option value="39">-Northern Ireland</option>
    <option value="40">-Scotland</option>
    <option value="41">-Wales</option>
</select>
```

I can't change the HTML, but need to split the select into two selects by jQuery first the show the top level choices then for example if Canada was chosen show a second drop down with the provinces. This has to be dynamic as the underlying list might change with the time.

I understand that it would be much easier if there would be optgroups but unfortunately this is out of my control. So basicly i need to convert this simple list into hierarchical select in the browser.

Comment: better construct the first select box the on change of that make ajax call to get the relevant data for second.

Comment: I think it would be easier if you use multiple selection boxes and make them nested...Check example 5 in this link http://kotowicz.net/jquery-option-tree/demo/demo.html. It is based on this plugin https://code.google.com/p/jquery-option-tree/ Check out the nested options in the second link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below query to split continents and countries select box.

**NOTE** - put `id="select"` for main select box.

```
$(function(){
    var continent='';

    $('#select option:gt(0)').each(function(){
      var value = $(this).val();
      //check if option text don't have '-' in it, then take it as
      // continent and create a select box with same id
      if($(this).text().indexOf("-")==-1 && continent!=value)
      {
        continent=value;
          $('#select').after('<select id="'+continent+'" style="display:none" class="country"></select>');
      }
      else
      {
        //add option to the newly created select box    
          $('#'+continent).append($(this));
      }  
    });

    //remove all country select box which are empty
    $('.country').filter(function(){
        return $(this).children().length ==0;
    }).remove();

    //bind change event to select box to show / hide country select box
    $('#select').change(function(){
       $('.country').hide();
       $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0bmbd4sr/7/)**